# How to change the specific item background color in bottom navigation in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, background, navigation

If I select the Particular item in bottom navigation, **left and right side item's** background color has to change. Please help me if anyone having any idea.Thank you in advance

Comment: do you want to change selected item color or rest of ?

Comment: If i select one item, left side and right side item's background color has to change.

Comment: I have 5 items in navigation. ex: If i select 2nd item 1st and 3rd item's bgcolor has to change.

Comment: i think you are asking wrong question

Comment: so this is the right answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58715082/12034846

Answer (score 1):

On your BottomNavigationView, inthe XML file, add a property called "app:itemBackground" and set a drawable.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_view_height"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_bottom_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

Then, create the drawable, giving it a normal drawable and a selected drawable. For the selected item, give it the flag android:state_selected="true" like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_item_bottom_nav_select" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_item_bottom_nav_deselect"/>
</selector>
```

The last part it's just create two new drawables (the example code above i called "*bg_item_bottom_nav_select*" and "*bg_item_bottom_nav_deselect*"). One for the item selected and another for the item when it's not selected. Customize it like you want.

Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: I have Five Items in the  bottom Navigation.. If I Use "<item android:drawable="@drawable/shadow_menu_left" android:state_checked="true"/>" Other four items BgColor will change. ex: If i select 2nd item 1st and 3rd items bgcolor has to change.