# Bottomnavigation selected item background color change

Tags: java, android, colors, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the selected item background color in bottomnavigation just like Google Play Store. I tried to solve it, but till now I haven't found a solution.

[image: google_play_bottomnavigation]

> Update

I found attribute called `app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle` and it should change the indicator color. But for some reason it doesn't work. Here is an picture how should this attribute work.
[image: bottomnavigation diagram]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the specific item background color in bottom navigation in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713182/how-to-change-the-specific-item-background-color-in-bottom-navigation-in-android)

Comment: My query was how to remove selected item background(https://ibb.co/MfLMG98) and your question solved my problem. LOL. I added app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/black"

Answer (score 3):

Try the below attribute. It worked for me.

```
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: This works in removing it / Making it transparent. but it does not work for applying a different color

Answer (score 2):

If your project uses `style.xml` file to theme the project add this code to that file. Note that your app's theme must extend from the `MaterialComponents` theme in order the coloring to work.

```xml
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">COLOR_FOR_ICONS_AND_SURFACES</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">COLOR_FOR_ON_ICONS_OR_ON_SURFACES</item>
</style>
```

This will change the colors system-wide. If you want to apply it to only specific components then in your `style.xml` again, you must define the color attributes as an overlay.

```xml
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">COLOR_FOR_ICONS_AND_SURFACES</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">COLOR_FOR_ON_ICONS_OR_ON_SURFACES</item>
</style>
```

The `bottomNavigationStyle` defined in the `Theme.App` will color all bottom navigation views by default. If you don't want this then you can apply the style to only particular `BottomNavigationView` by defining the `style` attribute of it. This will override the default style that was defined in the app theme.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView"
/>
```

Comment: this  isn't working with me.

Comment: If you don't implement it correctly obviosly it will not work. Share the code that shows how you implement it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved to change the color with the next style:

```
<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">
        @style/ShapeAppearance.M3.Comp.NavigationBar.ActiveIndicator.Shape
    </item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And in the BottomNavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

Step 1: define a Style for your Active Indicator

```
<style name="Theme.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator">
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Step 2: Use that style (Theme.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator) in your BottomNavigationView

```
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/testing_color"
            app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Theme.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

Comment: This one actually worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This method isn't working and isn't related to what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this style by default:

```
api "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1"
```

and used style: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Challenge" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#F7C500</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">#FFFFED</item>   <--- This is the color
</style>
```

For more information visit this [page](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigation.md)