# How to remove highlight around bottom navigation bar icon when selected?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have been trying to get rid of the oval highlight around my bottom navigation bar icon when selected, but to no avail.

[image]

These are my current kotlin codes in Android Studio:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#142C6E"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**bottom_nav_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey"  />
</selector>
```

**bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/feed"
        android:title="Feed"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/AI"
        android:title="AI"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_smart_toy_24"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bookmarks"
        android:title="Bookmarks"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_bookmarks_24"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_person_outline_24"
        />
</menu>
```

Any insights or solutions are much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the solution, although it is probably not the best.

In my `activity_main.xml` file, I set: `app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/theme"`,
where theme is the background colour of my bottom navigation bar.

Would love to know if there are more elegant solutions for this

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many answers, including setting custom selectors as the item background.

The only thing that worked was creating a custom theme for the bottom nav bar.

**your theme:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator">
        <item name="android:color">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**your xml layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
  ...
  app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Theme.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator"
/>
```

[Bottomnavigation selected item background color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100046/bottomnavigation-selected-item-background-color-change)